# Using parallel decoder in libavcodec/ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavcodec

### The problem

I am writing a simple program in C language which makes use of libavcodec (https://github.com/Dr-Noob/framepos/blob/master/framepos.c)

I have been working with h264 videos. While the decoding works, I can see that it's very slow, since it only uses 1 CPU core (I checked it with `top`). On the other hand, I know that ffmpeg, which uses the same libavocdec installed in my system, makes use of the parallel h264 decoder. I can test it with:

```
ffmpeg -c:v h264 -i test.mkv -f null -
```

With `top` I can see that it's running in parallel, and the speed is noticeably faster. I would like a solution that always gives me the possibility of decoding the video using all the CPU cores, not only in the case of the h264 codec.

### My research so far

Looking at the ffmpeg code, one can see that, to obtain the `AVCodec`, it uses the function `find_codec_or_die`. This will end up using `avcodec_find_decoder_by_name`. Actually, if in my program I use this function, asking for the `h264` decoder, I still get the sequential version. Moreover, using gdb in ffmpeg I have seen that the `AVCodec` in ffmpeg is called `ff_h264_decoder`, while in my code, gdb does not know which specific type is the codec. The `ff` suffix makes me think that this one is the parallel decoder (because it looks like `ff` has something to do with parallel in the ffmpeg context (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/pthread__frame_8c.html)). However, it seems that I am unable to get this codec.

What can I do to decode video in parallel using libavcodec in C?

Comment: `AVCodec` doesn't define multi-threading - it is `AVCodecContext::thread_count` property (which should be set before `avcodec_open2()`)
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVCodecContext.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting [gkv311](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12890689/gkv311) comment as an answer for future reference.

`AVCodec` does not have multi-threading functionality. It is stored inside `AVCodecContex`. So, a posible scheme to run the codec in parallel:

```
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder
AVCodecContext *ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3

ctx->thread_count = n_threads;
ctx->thread_type = FF_THREAD_FRAME;

avcodec_open2(ctx, fmt_ctx->video_codec, NULL)
```